# Maven - package web.xml generated by Configuration Processor Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

In our web.xml, there is a fragment that is required only for development, it must not be present when the app is deployed into production. I'd like to use the [Configuration Processor Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/) to remove this fragment when Maven has been invoked with production profile.

The transformation itself is easy, but **what would be the best way to package this generated web.xml to WAR file**? I'm outputting the transformed web.xml to directory *target/generated-sources*. 
When the production profile is active, I'd like Maven to use this web.xml instead the one in the src directory. If this profile is not active, then the standard location should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a property, say, `webXml.path` and configure Maven the following way:

```
<properties>
  <webXml.path>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml.path>
</properties
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <webXml>${webXml.path}</webXml>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
      <webXml.path>target/generated-sources/web.xml</webXml.path>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```